# Can I manage more wordpress sites with one wordpress administrator page?

Tags: multisite, admin

I would like to find a solution, where I can administer multiple wordpress sites (50 plus) using one wordpress admin interface or other tool. I would like to manage plugins and content on these sites.

Is there such tool exists?

Comment: Yes. It's called WordPress Multisite :)

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are not interested in multisite network, but in managing multiple separate blogs?

By description this sounds like [ManageWP](http://managewp.com/) (for the record hadn't used it myself).

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this, it works well - more limited than ManageWP but it's free:
https://wpremote.com
Lets you monitor the site and update WP, plugins and themes and create backups to download (used to store the backups on Amazon's S3 servers but that got too expensive). Also click to go to the home page or admin page, it doesn't save your login info so you'll have to log into admins yourself (or if the browser remembers your login).

Haven't tried this, it looks similar - they claim to be able to log you in to the admin with a click. Doesn't appear to update WP and plugins but it checks for malware:
https://portal.wpengine.com/

Answer (score 1):

Hi **@gyurisc:**

Easy: use [**WordPress Multisite**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network).

Comment: Can I use this multisite wordpress with different domains as well?

Comment: @gyurisc - You can use it with 1.) subdirectories, 2.) subdomains, or with the **[Domain Mapping Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/)**, you can use with whatever domains you want.

Answer (score 0):

I use ManageWP for up to 15 sites at the moment and I find it very useful.

Some of the messages are a bit basic and not very informative (eg "Working ....") but it has reduced the amount of time needed to administer a number of sites.

I have also used it to move and clone sites, again it is not a perfect tool but I have used it a number of times successfully (sometimes with a bit of "fixing" needed).

I am paying for it but also sell site management as a service, which covers the costs. I consider it well worth the cost for the time saved, the convenience and the ease of moving sites.

I have resisted adding an affiliate link :-)

Answer (score 0):

I use MAINWP https://mainwp.com/.

I set up a domain to host a singular wordpress site with the dashboard for MainWP then installed the child plugin to all the sites I want to manage.

Import the sites to the main site and manage them all from there. Has been excellent and its FREE..